# NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString leak

Tags: objective-c

I am getting NSCFString for the code below:

```
NSString *urlString;

/*  leak showing below line */

urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

How do you solve this leak?

Comment: Where did you get urlString in the first place? Do you need to release it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you created your urlString using `+alloc/initWith...`.  If that's the case then you own the `urlString` reference and are responsible for releasing it at some point.  However, when you get to the line you pasted in the question, you're overwriting the `urlString` reference with a new string reference, since `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` returns a new string object (ie, it doesn't modify the string in place).

My recommendation would be to use an `NSMutableString` instead, which does allow in-place string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You should do pointer allocation of string instead of static allocation. Change:

```
NSString urlString;
```

to:

```
NSString *urlString;
```

Also there seems to be some other code that initiates the `urlString` to some value to which you're doing the replace operation.

Comment: LOL I can't believe I didn't see that... whoops! :)

Comment: The compiler wouldn't let that compile anyway.  It can't be the source of the leak (at least, not without screwing mightily with build settings).

Answer (score 0):

it's from one my code is do all you want, i replaced to white space but you can replace to empty string (@"")

```
    NSString  * str_aLine;
    str_aLine = @"sometext \n and \t     and on";
    // replace tabs to space
    str_aLine = [str_aLine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@" "];
    // replace \n to space
    str_aLine = [str_aLine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
    // replace \r to space
    str_aLine = [str_aLine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@" "];
    // reduce spaces to one space
    str_aLine = [str_aLine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" +" withString:@" " options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str_aLine.length)];
    // trim begin and end from white spaces
    str_aLine = [str_aLine stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```